# Positive definite binary quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Please help me to solve this question or introduce references that help me:

Let $f(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ be a reduced positive definite form. 
Suppose that $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ and that $f(x, y) ≤ a + |b| + c$. Show 
that $f(x,y)$ must be one of the numbers $a, c, a - |b| + c$ or $a + 
|b| + c$.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the main thing is that
$$ f \geq \left( \frac{4ac - b^2}{4c} \right) x^2, $$
$$ f \geq \left( \frac{4ac - b^2}{4a} \right) y^2. $$
These just come from completing the square.

Reduced means $$ |b| \leq a \leq c  $$ with some additional conditions in case some things are equal. For example, $ac \geq b^2.$ Thus $4ac-b^2 \geq 3ac.$ Thus
$$ f \geq \left( \frac{3a}{4} \right) x^2, $$
$$ f \geq \left( \frac{3c }{4} \right) y^2. $$

Now, suppose $|y|\geq 2,$ so that $y^2 \geq 4$ and $f \geq 3c.$ With the condition $f \leq a + |b| + c$ and reduction this gives $y = \pm 2,$ $a = |b| = c$ and so $a=|b| = c = 1$ because $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1.$ Take $y=2$ and continue with $x^2 + 2x + 4.$

Next, if we do **not** have $a=|b| = c = 1,$ we have $y = \pm 1$ or $y=0.$ Continue with either $ax^2 + b x + c$ and $y=1$ or $a x^2$ with $y=0.$

Comment: How do you know that $\gcd(a, b, c) = 1$?  For example, $2x^2 \pm 2xy + 2y^2$ is a reduced positive definite binary quadratic form with $\gcd(a, b, c) = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer breaks the problem into three cases: $y = 0$, $y = \pm 1$, and $|y| \ge 2$.  Recall that because $f$ is reduced and positive definite, $|b| \le a \le c$.

Assume first that $y = 0$.  Then because $\gcd(x, y) = \gcd(x, 0) = 1$, $x$ must equal $\pm 1$.  In this case, $f(x, y) = f(\pm 1, 0) = a$, which satisfies the condition $f \le a + |b| + c$.

Next, assume that $y = \pm 1$.  If $x = 0$, then $f(0, \pm 1) = c$.  If $x = \pm 1$, then $f(\pm 1, \pm 1) = a \pm b + c = a \pm |b| + c$.  Each of those three representations meets the conditions $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ and $f \le a + |b| + c$.  If $|x| \ge 2$, we first derive the following inequality starting with the [triangle inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInequality.html):
\begin{align}
|2ax + by| & \ge |2ax| - |by|\\
           & \ge 4a - b &&\text{because } |x| \ge 2 \text{ and } y = \pm 1\\
           & \ge 4a - a &&\text{because } |b| \le a\\
           & = 3a
\end{align}
We now find a lower bound for $f(x, y)$:
\begin{align}
f(x, y) & = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2\\
& = \frac{1}{4a} \left( 4a^2x^2 + 4abxy + 4acy^2 \right)\\
& = \frac{1}{4a} \left( 4a^2x^2 + 4abxy + b^2y^2 - b^2y^2 + 4acy^2 \right)\\
& = \frac{1}{4a} \left( (2ax + by)^2 + (4ac - b^2)y^2 \right)\\
& \ge \frac{1}{4a} \left( (3a)^2 + 4ac - b^2 \right) &&\text{because } |2ax + by| \ge 3a \text{ and } y = \pm 1\\
& \ge \frac{1}{4a} \left( 9a^2 + 4ac - a^2 \right) &&\text{because } |b| \le a\\
& = 2a + c\\
& = a + a + c\\
& \ge a + |b| + c &&\text{because } |b| \le a
\end{align}
Due to the upper-bound condition $f \le a + |b| + c$, the only possible representation here is $f(x, \pm 1) = a + |b| + c$.

Finally, assume that $|y| \ge 2$.
\begin{align}
f(x, y) & = \frac{1}{4a} \left( (2ax + by)^2 + (4ac - b^2)y^2 \right) &&\text{as above}\\
& \ge \frac{4ac - b^2}{4a}y^2\\
& \ge \frac{4ac - b^2}{4a} \cdot 4 &&\text{because } |y| \ge 2\\
& = \frac{4ac - b^2}{a}\\
& \ge \frac{4ac - ac}{a} &&\text{because } |b| \le a \le c\\
& = 3c
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
3c \le f(x, y) & \le a + |b| + c &&\text{as just shown and using a required condition}\\
& \le 3c &&\text{because } |b| \le a \le c
\end{align}
Because both $f(x, y)$ and $a + |b| + c$ are sandwiched between $3c$ and $3c$, the only possible representation here is $f(x, y) = a + |b| + c$.

Thus, for all pairs of integers $(x, y)$ such that $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ and $f(x, y) \le a + |b| + c$, $f(x, y)$ must be one of the numbers $a$, $c$, $a - |b| + c$, or $a + |b| + c$.

Remark: This is Problem 7 of Section 3.7 and is similar to Lemma 3.24 in I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991.  That book is a helpful reference for questions like this.